# Dynamically regulate voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator

I wanted to know if it was possible to dynamically regulate voltage with, for example, a potentiometer which allows me to select output voltage and some kind of voltage regulator.

Suppose that I have a solar panel connected to this hypotethical voltage regulator; I want to be able to choose the output voltage of my regulator in 'real time' so that I can recharge for example batteries with different voltages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output voltage and voltage regulating are two different things. The second should be done by the regulator.

This is how you can achieve the first if you're using a [LM317](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm117.pdf):

With digital outputs:

[image]

And the potentiometer variant:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am studying your circuits since I am kind of new to this field

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use a switching converter, especially for charging batteries. The [LM2596](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) is easy to use and cheap.

[image: LM2596 circuit]
[image: LM2596]